# Javascript string manipulation with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
"#G=0&path=folder1"
```

I want to find a part after "path=" which is folder1 in this case, and replace it with something else, so the string will look like this:

```
"#G=0&path=file2"
```

How can I do this using Javascript regular expressions?

Comment: Are you using a document fragment as a query-string? Parsing query strings correctly is a bit more work than one simple regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible regex solution:

```
"#G=0&path=folder1".replace(/(&?path=).*$/, "$1" + "file2");
```

Or you can do it without regex:

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("=") + 1) + "file2";
```

Answer (score 0):

See, for example, [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), [MDN replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [here](http://www.sttmedia.com/regular-expressions), and educate yourself about regular expressions, they are very useful.

```
var str = '#G=0&path=folder1';
var file = 'file2';

str = str.replace( /^(#G=0&path=).+$/, '$1' + file );

console.log( str );    // #G=0&path=file2
```